# Project tiles from custom imagery in transverse mercator with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

I have the following parameters of a custom imagery and I need to set-up a layer in OpenLayers with which I would project the tiles properly from this imagery.

TransverseMercator
ellipsoidName=WGS84
equatorialRadius=6378137.0
inverseFlattening=298.257223563
falseEasting=500000.0
falseNorthing=0.0
origin=[latitude = 0.0 longitude = -117.0]
scale=0.9996